# Qjackctl alsa connections, what connects to what?

Tags: alsa, connection, midi

Trying to get my guitar going via midi usb cord and I just need to know what connects to what.  Here is a picture.

[image]

Comment: Any more explanation would be greatly appreciated.  I am brand new to this.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GzU0U86.png

Answer (score 0):

Connect the output of the USB MIDI cable to the input of whatever it is that you want the guitar connect to.
In this case, I'd guess the cable calls itself "mio", and you want to make sounds with rakarrack.